# Xamarin - Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to implement Google Maps into my Xamarin Android Application, but I continue to get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
```

I have tried changing the code to use *SupportMapFragment* and also used the documentations approach to implementing Google Maps. However, I can't seem to understand the issue at hand.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Support.V4.App;

namespace Fleet_Management_App
{
    [Activity(Label = "Fleet_Management_App", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        private GoogleMap _map;

        public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
        {
            _map = map;
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            SetupMap();
        }

        private void SetupMap()
        {
            FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map).GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="Fleet_Management_App.Fleet_Management_App" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_Key" android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_Key" android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
</manifest>
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thanks everyone.

Comment: Do you get the same error using SupportMapFragment?

Comment: @hichame.yessou Yes I do. I change the code in the SetupMap method and the Main.axml and I get the exact same error message.

Comment: Do you clean your solution/closing the .axml before trying again? Sometimes annoyingly it doesn't take account of new changes on the .axml

Comment: @hichame.yessou Yeah I've tried cleaning the solution and closing the .axml but I still get the `Error inflating class fragment` message

Comment: All right, last try, have you tried using class instead of android:name? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/creating-a-fragment/

Comment: Have you set the <meta-data> tags with com.google.android.gms.version and com.google.android.geo.API_KEY?

Comment: @hichame.yessou I tried using class instead of android:name but still get the same error

Comment: @MartinZikmund I have everything within my manifest file and still errors, I've added a copy of the manifest in the original post though